# Choppy Player Movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

For whatever reason, my player movement stutters every second or every other second, and I'm sure it's to do with my player movement code being in the wrong update method.

Here's my player movement code

```
  [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayerMask;
public float speed;
public float Jump;
public sword swordScript;
public GameObject swordSprite;
private float move;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private BoxCollider2D boxCollider2d;
private bool facingRight;
public SpriteRenderer spr;
public Animator PlayerAnims;
public bool movementAllowed;
public float knockback;


void Awake()
{
    boxCollider2d = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    facingRight = true;
    spr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    boxCollider2d = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    facingRight = true;
    spr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}



// Update is called once per frame

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(movementAllowed == true)
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);
        if (isGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Jump));
        }
    }
}


void Update()
{
    if (movementAllowed == true)
    {
        Flip(move);

        if (move == 0)
        {
            PlayerAnims.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerAnims.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
    }


}


private bool isGrounded()
{
    float extraHeightText = .1f;
    RaycastHit2D raycasthit2d = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2d.bounds.center, boxCollider2d.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down,  extraHeightText, groundLayerMask);
    Color rayColour;
    if (raycasthit2d.collider != null)
    {
        rayColour = Color.green;
        PlayerAnims.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    }
    else
    {
        rayColour = Color.red;
        PlayerAnims.SetBool("isJumping", true);

    }
    Debug.DrawRay(boxCollider2d.bounds.center + new Vector3(boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x, 0), Vector2.down * (boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText), rayColour);
    Debug.DrawRay(boxCollider2d.bounds.center - new Vector3(boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x, 0), Vector2.down * (boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText), rayColour);
    Debug.DrawRay(boxCollider2d.bounds.center - new Vector3(boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x, boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.y + extraHeightText), Vector2.right * (boxCollider2d.bounds.extents.x), rayColour);

    return raycasthit2d.collider != null;
}
private void Flip(float move)
{
    if (move > 0 && !facingRight || move < 0 && facingRight)
    {
        facingRight = !facingRight;

        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;

        theScale.x *= -1;

        transform.localScale = theScale;

        if (swordScript.isFollowing == true)
        {
            Vector3 swordScale = swordSprite.transform.localScale;

            swordScale.x *= -1;

            swordSprite.transform.localScale = swordScale;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out your script and I think I barely see that stutter, but one thing seems to fix it.

You have this particular line twice in the code for no reason

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);
```

Just remove the first one.

Comment: Thank you, i can't believe i didn't notice that before. I am still having this issue, but i'm sure i'll figure it out

Answer (score 0):

**As a rule of thumb:**

Calling `rb.AddForce`: This interacts with Physics - place it in `FixedUpdate`

Setting `rb.velocity`: This only sets a value. You are not triggering physics interactions with this - place it in `Update`

So, at first you should move your code which sets the velocity to the Update function. Also you are setting the velocity twice. Just remove the first line.

As an **example** here ist the Update and FixedUpdate function:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(movementAllowed == true)
    {
        if (isGrounded() && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, Jump));
        }
    }
}


void Update()
{
    if (movementAllowed == true)
    {
        float move = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(move * speed, rb.velocity.y);

        Flip(move);

        if (move == 0)
        {
            PlayerAnims.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerAnims.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are not using `move` anywhere else than `Update` you can just declare it as a local variable and remove the `private float move;` at the top of the script.

**Last thing which should be mentioned:**
You are getting component references both in Start or Awake. Generally you should get your references in Start and only get them in Awake when needed.

Comment: Thank you. This didn't fix my issue, i'm at a loss at this point but i appreciate the help!

Comment: I am not experiencing any choppy movement using the code from my answer. I think the Problem is somewhere else in you code